# How to send another job to a device before finishing the last job?

Tags: ibm-q-experience, vqe

Is there any way to create a for loop that would send a few jobs to run on a quantum computer simultaneously? I tried:

```
for i, entanglementor in enumerate(entanglement):
    print('\rentanglement: {}        '.format(entanglement[i]), end='')
    algorithm_globals.random_seed = 50
#ansatz = TwoLocal(rotation_blocks='ry', 
    entanglement_blocks='cz',entanglement=entanglement[i])
    form = EfficientSU2(num_qubits=2, entanglement=entanglement[i])
    #ansatz = RealAmplitudes(2, entanglement[i], reps=2, insert_barriers=True)
    optimizer = COBYLA(maxiter=5)
    counts = []
    values = []
    def store_intermediate_result(eval_count, parameters, mean, std):
    counts.append(eval_count)
    values.append(mean)

    vqe = VQE(form, optimizer, callback=store_intermediate_result,
          quantum_instance=QuantumInstance(backend=device))
    print("Running VQE algorithm on real hardware with device: ", device)
    vqe.ansatz.draw()
    result = vqe.compute_minimum_eigenvalue(operator=H2_op)
    converge_cnts[i] = np.asarray(counts)
    converge_vals[i] = np.asarray(values)
    print('\rentanglement complete      ');
```

The problem is that this sends one job to the QC, and then waits until it gets a result before continuing the loop, which can obviously take quite a while. Is there a method to get the loop to continue while a job is queued?

Comment: similar question: https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/14077/an-effective-way-to-submit-all-the-jobs-for-vqe-qaoa-at-a-time-to-an-ibmq-machin

Comment: may be a possible way: https://nonhermitian.org/posts/2021/2021-10-07-vqe_program.html#prerequisites with Qiskit Runtime

Comment: Check Qiskit Runtime: https://qiskit.org/documentation/apidoc/ibmq_runtime.html

Comment: Could use [IBMQJobManager](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.providers.ibmq.managed.IBMQJobManager.html#qiskit.providers.ibmq.managed.IBMQJobManager)

Comment: Yes try using the Job monitor